# Angular7 Promise cannot be used

Tags: promise, angular7

When I upgraded Angular6 to Angular7, I found that Promise didn't seem to work.

IDE gave me the following tips. I tried to search and couldn't understand why.

Unresolved type Promise less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Checks TypeScript called functions to be valid ones

Answer (score 0):

I try to add the following to `ts.config` as a solution.

```
"compilerOptions": {    "lib": ["es7", "dom"]}
```